# PHP form data, UTF-8 encoding, symbols are breaking

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have been tasked with making a simple 'cipher' script. The cipher is constructed by randomly substituting between other characters in the string provided, then issuing the substitutions as an additional string at the end of the cipher-text.

This seems to be working fine for alphanumeric characters, and some symbols. However, I tried to issue a GBP symbol (£) to the script, and it stopped working.

Now, I've checked that I am using UTF-8 encoding at every step of the way.

The script consists of 1 page. At the top of my PHP file, I have:

```
<?php header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

In my HTML page, I had this in the `<head>` area:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

In my 'cipher' and 'decipher' forms, I have:

```
accept-encoding="utf-8"
```

When I load the page in Chrome, it appears to be using the UTF-8 encoding when I check in Tools -> Encoding.

The issue seems to be that, as my script runs through each character one by one, it thinks that the GBP symbol is 2 characters in length. This is true even when I use `strlen` or `mb_strlen`.

Is there perhaps some way that I can strip the GBP symbol, and other symbols (yet to be tested) down to one character in length? Or will I need to program in some additional logic to detect that the current character is a special character of 2 in length, and move forward my iterator accordingly?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What *exactly* are you doing with that string?

Comment: You may find [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) helpful.

Comment: Http header keys are context sensitive! Have a try with `Content-type` instead of `content-type`. Yes, annoying, but documented and shown in all examples.

Comment: PHP does internally use Latin-1 for it's string functions, so you should use the multibyte functions whereever you are fiddling around with strings. Did you check this? Another solution could be using [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, so didn't want to leave my question unanswered, in case any other person came across a similar problem.

I am creating a very simple random substitution cipher. The cipher text should randomly substitute letters to other letters in the string. Therefore, the more letters you have, the more obfuscated it would appear to be. But the cipher text also includes the substitution table at the end of the string, in a random fashion. So, here are a few examples:

`Hello, World!`

becomes

`Ho,,!lrd! ,We rl,HHWd,l!eeor dWo!`,or `,Wlle!Hoe lrd Hr eW!doeWoH,lldr,!`, or `W,HHodleorH !d lH,doorr lHW!!e,We`.

I was iterating through the original string, finding the letter at the position in the loop, and storing an original and a substitution character. The problem for Unicode characters is that they appear to be prefixed with a Unicode translation character, which in fact turns it in to a 2 byte letter. In order to account for this, I simply detected whether the character currently being used at that position in the loop was character code 194, and if so, add the next character as part of the same 'letter'.

To find the character code, I used the following PHP code: `if(ord($letter) == 194){ ... }`

This successfully helped me to deal with all the characters I could possibly throw at it.